# php rename 2 uploaded files to specific names before upload

Tags: php, upload, file-rename

I'm currently using the following code to upload and rename a single file..

Form..

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formUploadFile">     
<label>Select file to upload:</label>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="btnSubmit"/>
</form>
```

and the follwing snippet of php does the magic..

```
     if($UploadOk == true){
                        $name = "foobar.csv";
                         move_uploaded_file($temp,$UploadFolder."/".$name);
                         array_push($uploadedFiles, $name);
}
```

But I'd now like to use it to upload 2 files and wish for the 1st to be renamed foobar.csv and the second to be renamed foobar2.csv how would I go about that?

I can upload the 2 files no problem, and rename the 1st also without issue my problem is in the renaming of the second file.

I've tried

```
$name = array("foobar.csv", "foobar2.csv");
```

and tried..

```
if($UploadOk == true){
                        $name = "foobar.csv";
                        $name2 = "foobar2.csv";
                        move_uploaded_file($temp,$UploadFolder."/".$name);
                        array_push($uploadedFiles, $name);
                        array_push($uploadedFiles, $name2);
                                    }
```

and also tried..

```
 if($UploadOk == true){
                            $name = "foobar.csv";
                            $name2 = "foobar2.csv";
                            move_uploaded_file($temp,$UploadFolder."/".$name);
                            array_push($uploadedFiles, $name, $name2);

                                        }
```

But none of these upload and rename the files.

Comment: Visit this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: I can upload the 2 files no problem,  and rename the 1st also without issue my problem is in the renaming of the second file. I've updated my OP to include this information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the array of `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']`. For example:

```
if ( $UploadOk == true ) {
    $name = "foobar.csv";
    $name2 = "foobar2.csv";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0], $UploadFolder."/".$name);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][1], $UploadFolder."/".$name2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this..

```
if($_FILES){
    $files = $_FILES['files'];
    $name = array("foobar.csv", "foobar2.csv"); 
    foreach($files['tmp_name'] as $index => $value){
        move_uploaded_file($value,$name[$index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this code does indeed rename the files but if I use it I no longer get the "success" message after upload. I have tried adding array_push($uploadedFiles, $name); and its also now ignoring $UploadFolder = "tmp_csv_store"; and instead uploading to the same directory as the script full code now here  https://pastebin.com/57ps4j00

Comment: okay, make changes in this line(line 53) in your code move_uploaded_file($temp,$UploadFolder."/".$name); -----move_uploaded_file($temp,$UploadFolder."/".$name[$key]);

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply, I gave the other answer a try while waiting and got it working great with that one. If i could accept 2 answers I would but Im going to give it to the other answer as that was the first I got to work how i'd wanted. thanks again for your help and time.